# How to extract a single value from the array returned by wp_get_post_terms

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

In Wordpress I want to display the term attached to a post in the taxonomy 'chapters'].
I can get the taxonomy information for a post using

```
$sectiondata = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'chapters', array("fields" => "all"));
```

Then using

```
print_r $sectiondata;
```

I can display the array of values returned.

However, how do I echo the value for the 'name' of the term to the page?
I thought this should be something like:

```
echo $sectiondata->name;
```

But that returns nothing so I obviously don't understand how to extract this value from the array. I've searched around for examples and don't see anything that explains how to display the value on the page, or perhaps better stated how to extract the value from the array. I've tried using the plain php approach of

```
print($sectiondata['name']);
```

But that doesn't return anything either.

Where can I find an explanation of how to extract the value from the array.

Comment: can you post the output of the `print_r` please?

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 126 [name] => 2. Measuring Value [slug] => 2-measuring-value [term_group] => 0 [term_order] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 142 [taxonomy] => chapters [description] => An introduction to the measurement of company value. [parent] => 81 [count] => 5 ) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're not looping through the array returned.  Before I show you how to do this with wp_get_post_terms, have you tried using the get_terms function?  I believe this may be a better approach for you:

```
$terms = get_terms('chapters');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'species').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

...

If that doesn't work for you check out how you can use wp_get_post_terms to do pretty much the same thing:

```
echo "<ul>";
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'chapters');
foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo "<li><a href='".get_term_link($term)."' title='".$term->name."'>".$term->name."</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

I hope this helps you out!  Let me know if there's any issue with either code example above.

Comment: Thanks that works. The first solution returns the list of terms in the taxonomy and I need the term/s attached to a single post. Note for other readers if you use the code in the first example you need to match up the use of the "taxonomy" name, ie species should be "chapters" or vice versa. The second solution provides the answer.

Comment: I want to add some details as sometime you have just one term associated to the post, or you have many but you want to display just one of them. In that case you may avoid the foreach loop, and just call the first term of the array: echo $terms[0]->name (naturally with the zero you get the first term of the array)